# The German letter in "Foundation of analysis" by Landau

Tags: notation

May someone help me with the alphabet in Landau's foundation of analysis?
I had search the web for [Fraktur](http://feefhs.org/guides/German_Gothic.pdf) but cannot find the same letters used in the book. For example, 
[Small German letter will stand for complex numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoWiv.jpg)

I really don't get know how the small german letter alphabet should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the reputation to comment, but maybe the following link will help:

http://www.altdeutsche-schrift.de/beispiele.html

If I see it correctly the two small letters in the link are x and y.

Comment: Thank you very much. How about the large letter? Does it stand for "H" ?

Comment: $\Xi$ (xi) is from the Greek alphabet (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet)

Comment: see here i hope this is what you are searchung for http://www.cis.rit.edu/~rvrpci/teaching/LaTeX/symbols-letter.pdf

Comment: The printed k is a bit odd in the www.altdeutsche-schrift.de site.  Maybe MathJax is better:  $\mathfrak{k}$.